# PROVIDE_BACKGROUND permission not longer needed?

Tags: permissions, wear-os

According to https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/service.html, I need the two privileges shown here from my manifest file:

```
      <!-- Required to act as a custom watch face. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<!-- So we can keep the screen on and start vibrations -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

However, starting recently (perhaps since I upgraded my watch to 6.0?) I see the following in the log:

`06-07 12:14:24.609 470-493/? W/PackageManager: Unknown permission com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND in package com.pipperpublishing.refwatch`

I've Googled for any changes in the permission model, perhaps associated with the new model in 6.0, but can't find anything about this.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE: Looking at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html it's clear that PROVIDE_BACKGROUND is no longer there, but I can't find anything that says it's been replaced or why it's no longer needed.

Comment: I have put in a request to get the documentation for this corrected. It was never needed in the first place, and the samples do not use it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I relayed this question over to the Wear development community on G+, and according to a Google dev advocate there, this permission was never actually used - and is safe to remove from your manifests.

Reference: https://plus.google.com/+SterlingUdell/posts/hvec9y93Gtf

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the follow-up; I didn't think to actually ask Google :)

Comment: The official sample https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace does not use this permission either. I should get the documentation link you mentioned updated to reflect this.